# Why can I access the encrypted S3 file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I've got an AWS key generated and an S3 file which I wanted to encrypt server-side. I don't understand why one of the users can decrypt it though. The setup I've got is:

Key with 3 policy statements:

- `arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root` with access to `kms:*`
- `arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/bank_trans_admin` with access to `kms:Encrypt` and `kms:DescribeKey`
- Instance profile with access to `kms:Decrypt` and `kms:DescribeKey`

I'm using `aws-vault` with the `bank_trans_admin` configured. Using that, I uploaded some file, which worked as expected:

```
aws-vault exec bank_trans_admin -- aws s3 cp --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id alias/TransactionAccountsKey the_file s3://some-bucket/
```

I verified in the AWS web console that the file is encrypted using KMS/sse.

But now I wanted to make sure I can't use decryption on the same account, so I did:

```
aws-vault exec bank_trans_admin -- aws s3 cp --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id alias/TransactionAccountsKey s3://some-bucket/the_file the_file
```

and it worked! I expected to be denied access, since I allowed only `Encrypt` for this IAM user. What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens when bank_trans_admin has **no** permissions on the key?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That was a good question. Removing all key statements from that user didn't change the situation. I forgot that the user is an admin on KMS. If that's what you were thinking, do you want to submit it as answer?

Comment: I did suspect that it might work anyway, but it was something of an intuitive guess. Honestly, though, the mechanism that SSE-KMS uses to assert the user's identity to KMS is not clear to me.  Does KMS implicitly trust S3's assertion of the identity of the authenticated user?  "Hi, I need this key because Mallory asked me to ask you for it" seems unconvincing.  Before answering, I'd like to understand how and why a user's permission on the key allows the request to pass through another service (S3) with the original requester's identity intact --  intuition isn't satisfied with "it just does."